# Leer un archivo json que tiene comentarios en python

Tags: python-3.x, json

Mi pregunta es solo como leer un archivo de json que tiene comentarios ya que solo me da error el prgrama si el json tiene los comentarios:

```
from json import loads

with open("./.vscode/launch.json") as f:
    dato = f.read()
json_lc = loads(dato)
print(json_lc)
print(json_lc["version"])
```

no es nada del otro mundo, solo lo hice para practicar, el json es uno que te da vs code por defecto:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Archivo actual",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 1):

*JSON* por especificación **no soporta comentarios**.

Sin embargo, si quieres agregar algo como un comentario debe ser un **dato**, es decir debe estar correctamente formateado como especifica el *JSON*. Por ejemplo, puedes agregar una llave `_comentario` e incluir esa data ahí.

```
{
"_comentary": " Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.\n Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes. \n For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387",
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Archivo actual",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
 ]

}
```

Por otro lado, los parsers en particular el de JSON esta hecho para seguir esta especificacion, asi que la solucion consiste en quitarlos o incluirlos como una llave para adherirse a su formato.